# Modify a node, when another node is being saved?

Tags: drupal, drupal-node-hook

How to modify another node, when another node is being saved?

i.e can I use a node_save($nid_to_be_saved) in side a hook_node_presave($node_being_saved)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use node_save in hook_node_presave provided the node that is being saved is not saved again. If you want to do that you need to have a flag in the node object `$node->presave_saved = TRUE;` and do not save again to avoid loops.